# excel conditional formatting vlookup does not contain value

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have a formular for conditional formatting:

```
=VLOOKUP(H4;Anothersheet.A$4:$A$20;1;FALSE)=H4
```

When the value of `H4` is found in the given range `Anothersheet.A$4:$A$20`, the cell gets colored in red. But I want to color the cell red if the value is not found. How can i achieve this?

I have tried the following formulars:

- `=VLOOKUP(H4;Anothersheet!$A$4:$A$20;1;FALSE)<>H4`
- `=NOT(VLOOKUPH4;Anothersheet!$A$4:$A$20;1;FALSE)=H4)`

But this doesn't work. In both cases the cell does not get colored (if the value exists in the given range and if the value does not exist in the given range).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User `COUNTIF()` for this:

```
=COUNTIF(Anothersheet!$A$4:$A$20,H4)=0
```

When not found your `VLOOKUP()` returns `#N/A`.

That being said, you can also edit your formula into:

```
=ISERROR(VLOOKUP(H4;Anothersheet!$A$4:$A$20;1;FALSE))
```

Comment: I've used ISERROR. This works for me, thanks. But what i don't understand: When VLOOKUP returns #N/A why does my formular not work? #N/A is not the value in H4 so this formular should have worked or am I missing something?

Comment: @Olli `#N/A=H4` returns `#N/A`.